# 241. Different Ways to Add Parentheses - a bug that I cannot understand and very INTERESTING

Tags: java, python, algorithm, debugging

Question statement:

```
Given a string of numbers and operators, return all possible results from computing all the different possible ways to group numbers and operators. The valid operators are +, - and *.

Example 1:

Input: "2-1-1"
Output: [0, 2]
Explanation: 
((2-1)-1) = 0 
(2-(1-1)) = 2
Example 2:

Input: "2*3-4*5"
Output: [-34, -14, -10, -10, 10]
Explanation: 
(2*(3-(4*5))) = -34 
((2*3)-(4*5)) = -14 
((2*(3-4))*5) = -10 
(2*((3-4)*5)) = -10 
(((2*3)-4)*5) = 10
```

I have a bug that I cannot figure out why it is not working. I debugged and it feels strange. I cannot figure out why? Maybe it has something to do with the Python language?

Here is my code:

```
class Solution:
    def diffWaysToCompute(self, input: str) -> List[int]:
        ways = []
        for i in range(0, len(input)):
            c = input[i]
            
            if c == '+' or c == '-' or c == '*':
                left, right = self.diffWaysToCompute(input[0:i]), self.diffWaysToCompute(input[i+1:])
                
                print(left, right)
                
                for l in left:
                    for r in right:
                        if c == '+':
                            print(int(l), int(r))
                            print(int(l) + int(r))
                            ways.append(int(l) + int(r))
                            break
                        elif c == '-':
                            print(int(l), int(r))
                            print(int(l) - int(r))
                            ways.append(int(l) - int(r))
                            break
                        elif c == '*':
                            print(int(l), int(r))
                            print(int(l) * int(r))
                            ways.append(int(l) * int(r))
                            break
            
        if len(ways) == 0:
            ways.append(int(input))
        print(ways)
        
        return ways
```

The output is

```
[2]
[3]
[4]
[5]
[4] [5]
4 5
20
[20]
[3] [20]
3 20
-17
[3]
[4]
[3] [4]
3 4
-1
[-1]
[5]
[-1] [5]
-1 5
-5
[-17, -5]
[2] [-17, -5]
2 -17
-34
[2]
[3]
[2] [3]
2 3
6
[6]
[4]
[5]
[4] [5]
4 5
20
[20]
[6] [20]
6 20
-14
[2]
[3]
[4]
[3] [4]
3 4
-1
[-1]
[2] [-1]
2 -1
-2
[2]
[3]
[2] [3]
2 3
6
[6]
[4]
[6] [4]
6 4
2
[-2, 2]
[5]
[-2, 2] [5]
-2 5
-10
2 5
10
[-34, -14, -10, 10]
```

It is missing 2 * -5 = -10.

But when I run the Java version (exactly the same), it is working. This is the Java version:

```
class Solution {
    public List<Integer> diffWaysToCompute(String input) {
        List<Integer> ways = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            char c = input.charAt(i);
            if (c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '*') {
                List<Integer> left = diffWaysToCompute(input.substring(0, i));
                List<Integer> right = diffWaysToCompute(input.substring(i + 1));
                
                System.out.println(left + " " + right);
                for (int l : left) {
                    for (int r : right) {
                        switch (c) {
                            case '+':
                                System.out.println(l + " " + r);
                                System.out.println(l + r);
                                ways.add(l + r);
                                break;
                            case '-':
                                System.out.println(l + " " + r);
                                System.out.println(l - r);
                                ways.add(l - r);
                                break;
                            case '*':
                                System.out.println(l + " " + r);
                                System.out.println(l * r);
                                ways.add(l * r);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (ways.size() == 0) {
            ways.add(Integer.valueOf(input));
        }
        
        System.out.println(ways);
        return ways;
    }
}
```

And here is the output:

```
[2]
[3]
[4]
[5]
[4] [5]
4 5
20
[20]
[3] [20]
3 20
-17
[3]
[4]
[3] [4]
3 4
-1
[-1]
[5]
[-1] [5]
-1 5
-5
[-17, -5]
[2] [-17, -5]
2 -17
-34
2 -5
-10
[2]
[3]
[2] [3]
2 3
6
[6]
[4]
[5]
[4] [5]
4 5
20
[20]
[6] [20]
6 20
-14
[2]
[3]
[4]
[3] [4]
3 4
-1
[-1]
[2] [-1]
2 -1
-2
[2]
[3]
[2] [3]
2 3
6
[6]
[4]
[6] [4]
6 4
2
[-2, 2]
[5]
[-2, 2] [5]
-2 5
-10
2 5
10
[-34, -10, -14, -10, 10]
```

The problem is in the Python version, somehow 2 * -5 was ignored. But according to the statement for r in right, -5 should not get ignored. It really doesn't make sense to me, like 1 + 1 = 3 nonsense. Can anyone please elaborate? Much appreciated!

Comment: you could add some messages in `print()` in `output` to see which part of code is executed - ie. `"l+r = "`. Current `output` is unreadable for us.

Comment: You could also display what you have in other variables - specially in `input`. Different languages may send data to functions in different way. I'm not sure but Java may duplicate `input` when it send to functions but Python may send only reference.

Comment: Java does not duplicate input as a parameter, but String is immutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `break` statements that you put in your if/elif conditions.  They are not needed and actually stop the `for r in right` loop.

You could do this using a recursive generator to produce the formulas and compute the results using eval().  The logic would probably be a bit simpler:

```
import re
def addPar(S):
    parts  = re.split("([\+\-\*])",S)  # split on operators (keep separators)
    if len(parts)==1: yield S;return   # no operation -> string itself
    for i in range(1,len(parts)-1,2):  # for each operation
        ls = "".join(parts[:i])        # left side operand 
        rs = "".join(parts[i+1:])      # right side operand
        # recursively add parentheses...
        yield from (f"({L}{parts[i]}{R})" for L in addPar(ls) 
                                          for R in addPar(rs))
```

output:

```
for f in addPar("2*3-4*5"): print(f,eval(f))

(2*(3-(4*5))) -34
(2*((3-4)*5)) -10
((2*3)-(4*5)) -14
((2*(3-4))*5) -10
(((2*3)-4)*5) 10

print(sorted(map(eval,addPar("2*3-4*5"))))
[-34, -14, -10, -10, 10]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes perfect sense!